# How to tackle the delay in loading an activity?

Tags: android

I have made changes to my code, as I have given `this.setContentView(sv);` right at the beginning of `onCreate()`, but the view is loading only after executing try catch it seems. Is it really possible to show the view before executing try catch?

```
public class viewstoryActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        this.setContentView(sv);
        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */

        try {
            LinearLayout layout[];
            TextView name[];
            ImageView website[];
            TextView category[];
            URL url = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?start-index=1&max-results=25&vq=itsaperfectstory&orderby=relevance");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");

            /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
            layout = new LinearLayout[nodeList.getLength()];
            name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            website = new ImageView[nodeList.getLength()];
            category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                layout[i]= new LinearLayout(this);
                layout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                layout[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.allicon_bg);
                layout[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,150));
                name[i] = new TextView(this);
                website[i] = new ImageView(this);
                category[i] = new TextView(this);

                name[i].setPadding(50, 20,0,0);
                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                name[i].setText(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                final String url1 = websiteElement.getAttribute("url");
                NodeList websiteList1 = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("media:thumbnail");
                Element websiteElement1 = (Element) websiteList1.item(1);
                String test=websiteElement1.getAttribute("url");

                Bitmap bm = null;
                URL aURL = new URL(test);
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close();
                is.close();  // TODO: handle exception

                website[i].setImageBitmap(bm);
                website[i].setMaxWidth(50);
                website[i].setPadding(380, 0, 0, 0);
                layout[i].addView(name[i]);
                layout[i].addView(website[i]);
                layout1.addView(layout[i]);
                layout[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        // add data to bundle
                        bundle.putString("url", url1);
                        Intent intent=new Intent(viewstoryActivity.this, VidActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                        overridePendingTransition (R.anim.right_slide_out, R.anim.right_slide_out);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Parsing Exception = " + e);
        }

        /** Set the layout view to display */
        sv.addView(layout1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After analyzing your `onCreate()`, it is obvious that your Activity would take a while to show. All of your UI is designed and added dynamically and **must** (according to your code) wait for the data to load and be parsed and organized. In other words, you are blocking your UI with your data processing.

Consider moving your data loading to an `AsyncTask`. Also consider designing/loading your UI **before** the data. This would allow your user to see *something*, even if its not complete. And you can always add Views or change the display properties after the `onCreate()`. It will also get reduce the perception of the UI lag.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said move your work into an AsyncTask so that it's not blocking main thread. If you're interested in seeing exactly what's taking all the time then I'd suggest taking some time to read up on TraceView - it's a great tool for profiling.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion move big try block to another thread, don't block the ui.

Comment: `try` does not block the UI in any way. It simply allows the developer to handle exceptions. In fact, there are many studies that show `try/catch` have a negligible effect on performance. Additionally, most of OP's layout code is IN the `try/catch` block. This means he could not move the block to another thread even if he wanted to. Please reanalyze the code and provide a more accurate suggestion. If you do this I'll remove my vote down.

Comment: i not mean the `all try block ui`, i just mean in the pasted code.

Comment: And I maintain that there is a ton of UI code in there, and many of his calls will not work in another thread; only the UI thread. :) Your response is enough for me to remove my vote down, but really take a look if you are going to provide an answer. You obviously have the skill to provide a serious and useful answer. :)

Comment: thank you for your comments, i will not make it happen again.